# Create React App jsx-a11y/accessible-emoji warning won't go away

Tags: emoji, create-react-app

Im getting a `jsx-a11y/accessible-emoji` warning from Create React App using emojis.

To solve this I tried making a component with the accessibility requirements, however Im still getting the warnings:

```
const EmojiWrap = props => {
  return (
    <span role="img" aria-label="sheep">
      {props.children}
    </span>
  );
};

<EmojiWrap></EmojiWrap>
```

I belive this should work so could this be a bug with eslint / create react app?

Ive also tried using `aria-hidden="true"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution I found is [Sean McPherson's a11y-react-emoji Component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/a11y-react-emoji).

Add `a11y-react-emoji` to your project:

```
npm install a11y-react-emoji
# or
yarn add a11y-react-emoji
```

Import the Emoji component and use it:

```
import Emoji from 'a11y-react-emoji';

function EmojiExample() {
    return (
        <Emoji symbol="" label="sheep" />
    )
}
```

Full credit to Sean and [his article on Medium](https://medium.com/@seanmcp/-introducing-a11y-react-emoji-8b0c31a96814).

Answer (score 4):

Not ideal but you can disable the warnings by adding this to the file:

```
/* eslint-disable jsx-a11y/accessible-emoji */
```

Comment: Disabling an eslint rule is always an option, but doing so for accessibility errors is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you're here in 2023, just disable it with

```js
/* eslint-disable jsx-a11y/accessible-emoji */
```

---

This rule was valid at one point of time, but no longer is - assistive technologies have improved in emoji detection.
I quote from the [relevant discussion](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/issues/627) by the maintainer:

> Emojis have evolved since this rule was created and it no longer makes sense. I'm going to deprecate this rule in the current version and we'll remove it in the next version.